# Java/Android: Easiest way to convert xml to a loopable object? (Map?)

Tags: java, android, xml, dictionary

I have a string containing XML content with the following structure. My question is, how do i easily convert it to an object of some sort, and then loop through all of the items within ?

Are there any easy to use libraries that does this? If so, examples would be great. I recently got in to Java developing and i'm still learning.

I just read about XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html), and it seems very promising. I just don't know how to properly apply it.

```
<requests>
    <0>
        <id>1</id>
        <key>sms_number</key>
        <value>0709601159</value>
    </0>
    <1>
        <id>1</id>
        <key>sms_text</key>
        <value>This is a text message, blablabla.</value>
    </1>
</requests>
```

Any suggestions, ideas or examples are very appreciated.

Comment: in <requests> you could just have <request id="1" key="sms_number">0709601159</request> which would be easier to read with any XML library and it uses attributes... Or with how I see it: <request id="1"> <value key="sms_number">0709601159</value> <value key="sms_text">This is a text message</value> </request>

Comment: So let's say i have 10 different <request> tags with the keys as attributes instead, would it still be easier? And, doesn't that kind of destroy part of the point of using XML?

Comment: The point of XML is to store data of any kind... How would that destroy the point? You don't need to name the tags after number. After I read again I think my second idea is better, heh. It just puts things into where they belong!

Comment: You're right, ok. You said it would be easier to do it this way, could you possibly give me an example of that? Or push me in the right direction?

Comment: I would try it this way: http://pastebin.com/wgr8y4cd It looks a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that defines what the object is:

```
public class Term implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String word;
private String abbr1;
private String abbr2;
private String definition;
private String formula;

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}
public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
public String getAbbr1() {
    return abbr1;
}
public void setAbbr1(String abbr1) {
    this.abbr1 = abbr1;
}
public String getAbbr2() {
    return abbr2;
}
public void setAbbr2(String abbr2) {
    this.abbr2 = abbr2;
}
public String getDefinition() {
    return definition;
}
public void setDefinition(String definition) {
    this.definition = definition;
}
public String getFormula() {
    return formula;
}
public void setFormula(String formula) {
    this.formula = formula;
}
```

}

Then use an XML parser to parse through your XML:

```
public ArrayList<Term> getTerms(){
    ArrayList<Term> termsList = new ArrayList<Term>();

    //create array lists for the four attributes of each term
    ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> abbr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> abbr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> definition = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> formula = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Strings for each of the attributes
    String currentWord = null;
    String currentAbbr1 = null;
    String currentAbbr2 = null;
    String currentDefinition = null;
    String currentFormula = null;



    //try to parse the XML into the four array lists
    try{

        //get the xml document and put it into a reader
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.terminology);

        //set the eventType and the boolean to test if finished.
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        boolean done = false;

        /*
         * while statement that will read through the xml document and includes
         * a switch case block that will go through the tags and put the attributes
         * into the appropriate array lists
         */
        while (eventType !=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done){
            String name = null;
            switch (eventType){
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("terminology")){

                }else if (word != null && abbr1 != null && abbr2 != null && definition != null && formula != null){
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("term")){

                    }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("word")){
                        currentWord = new String(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("abbr1")){
                        currentAbbr1 = new String(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("abbr2")){
                        currentAbbr2 = new String(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("definition")){
                        currentDefinition = new String(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("formula")){
                        currentFormula = new String(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("formula") && currentFormula != null){
                    formula.add(currentFormula);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("definition") && currentDefinition != null){
                    definition.add(currentDefinition);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("abbr2") && currentAbbr2 != null){
                    abbr2.add(currentAbbr2);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("abbr1") && currentAbbr1 != null){
                    abbr1.add(currentAbbr1);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("word") && currentWord != null){
                    word.add(currentWord);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("term")){
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("terminology")){
                    done = true;
                }
                break;  
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }



    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){

    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }

    for (int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
        Term term = new Term();
        term.setWord(word.get(i));
        term.setAbbr1(abbr1.get(i));
        term.setAbbr2(abbr2.get(i));
        term.setDefinition(definition.get(i));
        term.setFormula(formula.get(i));
        termsList.add(term);


    }


    return termsList;
}
```

This has been wonderful for me.  it's a lot of code, but it works, pretty quickly too actually.  I notice no lag time, and there are nearly 30 "terms" in my XML, each with 5 attributes.  just store your XML under res/xml (you will likely have to create the XML folder).

Comment: Whoa, that is a lot of code. Especially for someone who's barely familiar with Java, haha. Thank you, i'll try to read it through. But as a follow up question; why is it so much more complex to do in Java compared to for example PHP?

Comment: @qwerty This is because Java strictly forces typing. You need to write everything out in classes... But of course it's also possible to use the approach like PHP does... Just putting it into tons of maps (key-value pairs) :). It's just that it's not very clean against having a class structure representing your XML.

Comment: @qwerty - This is only my first full android app.  I've worked on two others that were not nearly this complex.  Google and SO have been great friends these last 5 months as I've worked on this project.

Comment: Found a good tutorial for XOM, it does the job. Thanks for the explanation and the help! If i had more time i would read in to it more, but i'm on a deadline and i have to get this done as fast as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but you could also consider using Simple: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize

It has a pretty comprehensize set of tutorials and if I remember correctly, it's quite small, so it shouldn't add much size to your application.

As with most of these XML parsing libraries, you'll need to create a data object of some sort to hold your deserialized data and you'll need to add some tags in that class to let the deserializer know what data you want to capture from the XML file and where to store it.